# iOS how to detect swipe left or right on UICollectionView that otherwise only scrolls vertically?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swipe-gesture

My collection view is working great. It shows a grid of photos and lists hundreds of them. You can swipe vertically to scroll through them all. Life is good. However, I now have a new requirement. I need to be able to detect when the user is swiping left or right. I need to be able to intercept this gesture so I can attach behavior to left and right swipes while keeping intact my collection view's vertical scroll capabilities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two recognizers, one for swiping left, and the other for swiping right:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeUpGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeftFrom:)];
swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
```

and for the handler:

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeftFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

}
```

Finally, you add it to your view:

```
[view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGestureRecognizer];
```

The same for the other direction (just change all the Lefts to Rights).

Answer (score 0):

add UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the cells settings its direction as below,

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightDir = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeRightDirection:)];
    swipeRightDir.delegate = self;
    swipeRightDir.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [swipeRightDir setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
```